# Can I create a map in Firestore Rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have for every document an array of admins that are allowed access to that document. The items in the array are all objects similar to this:

```
[
    {user_ID : "Wfdwwwrdfsdfsdf",
    avatar: "www.dfsfsd.com/dfdfd"
    name: "Ben Ben"
    },
    {user_ID : "Hdfsdbbf",
    avatar: "www.dfsfsd.com/popo"
    name: "Josh Josh"
    }
]
```

In my Firestore Rules I want to check the user making the request is an admin, so I need to check if their uid is part of this array. In JS, I'd just create a new array from the array admins that would only include the IDs, using a map, and check if the ID is there. In Firestore Rules that doesn't seem to be an option. How can I get around this?
Do I have to create another array that only stores the IDs of admins for every document? That seems excessive.
Can't really find all the methods and functions that I can use when workign with Firestore. All I find are examples for certain operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do loops in the rules, so you wont be able to go through the objects and create an array of ID. Having this array of admins pre-calculated seems the best option then you would just do

```
 allow update: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.admins
```

The other option is to transform your array of admins into a map with the uid as the key. Then you dont need to duplicate the keys.

```
{
    Wfdwwwrdfsdfsdf : {
        avatar: "www.dfsfsd.com/dfdfd"
        name: "Ben Ben"
    },
    Hdfsdbbf: {
        avatar: "www.dfsfsd.com/popo"
        name: "Josh Josh"
    }
}
```

The rule remains the same

The reference containing all the functions you can use is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules)